# Can JOIN or UNION collapse mutiple rows for use in a subquery

Tags: t-sql

I'd like to get all tags that match a given id where:

```
select tag where id = 101 //returns 4 rows
soup
nuts
juice
milk
```

Only now, i'd like to use that as a subquery -

```
select idList, (select tag where id = 101) itemsOnList, shopper from assignedLists
```

becomes:

```
10 | soup,nuts,juice,milk | Mom
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a pretty tricky thing to do believe or not.
The best reference I have seen for doing this is [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/). The following query was taken from an example in that article. There are more options.

```
select
  idList,
  (
    select name + ','
    from tag
    where id = 101
    for xml path('')
  ) as itemsOnList,
  shopper
from
  assignedLists
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/67973/) out. Free Subscription required (if you're a sql programmer you need to have access to this site anyways)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) command.  It wouldn't do exactly what you want but it is similar.  If you wanted to literally do that, i.e. turn a data set into a scalar value of a comma seperated string you would have to create a user defined scalar function that took a table parameter.